# The weirdest issue with lamp+mediawiki ever experienced

Tags: php, apache, networking, mediawiki

Ok, so I have set up a installation of lamp and mediawiki on my machine with the path `http://localhost/mw/`. I then proceeded to install windows on a virtual machine so i could test mediawiki installation with Internet Explorer. So i set the appropriate $wgServer setting to my host IP addr which was reachable from the virtualbox client.

First i accessed `http://x.x.x.x/` and got a directory listing, yay it works. right?.... NO..

I then proceeded to access `http://x.x.x.x/mw/` (mediawiki path), and to my suprise, IE was just loading on recieve. Several hours went by, and still IE was loading the page... No connection timeout, no recieve timeout. just loading.. forever and ever...

When trying to investigate what was really going on here, i downloaded the cli utility cURL. and proceeded with the command: `curl -v http://x.x.x.x/mw/index.php/Main_Page`. I was able to retrieve the page, however the result was mind blowing!

First off, mediawiki reports that the page was rendered quite fast (as read from the recieved html source)

```
Served in 0.356 secs.
```

Curl on the other hand;

```
* 14542 bytes transfered in 764.580 seconds (19 bytes/sec).
```

This suggests to me that for some reason the path `/mw/...` has a very slow transfer rate. All the other sites works just fine, but not `/mw/`

And since i never got a connection timeout or receive timeout in IE im guessing that i'm recieving byte for byte at a very slow rate, and it does this for all the resources on the page im trying to get.

And to make things even more interesting, the host machine can access `/mw/` without any problems at all. I also tried connecting with another computer on the network (not a virtual machine), and it also suffered the same issue with endless loading.

Any ideas on what is going on here?

Comment: Can you try enabling $wgDebugLogFile in LocalSettings.php and then see if it logs anything noteworthy?

http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgDebugLogFile

Comment: Of topic, kind of.. If you wish to test in different browsers, all you need is a public accessible webserver and BrowserStack.com - Remember you can password protect your public webserver with httpauth.

Comment: This has nothing to do with browsers.. This is a network/latency issue. Caused by xdebug a debugging module for php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to be traced back to xdebug module when configured with auto connect back.

Removing `xdebug.xdebug.remote_connect_back` in xdebug config solved the issue.